# UI Test{Capybara + Cucumber]: How to check if a specific text box has a focus

Tags: gwt, focus, cucumber, capybara

Hi I am currently testing to see if a specific field has focus when the page loads.
I could not find anywhere on how to do this.
Basically what I want to do is to check if a specific element in a page has focus.
Is there any built in method to check this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document.activeElement` gives it, but that property is only available in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in method to tell you what has focus.

The only way I know and the method i use is the following. I attach a focus and blur event at the base widget that contains all the text element and keep track of it my self.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test if an element has focus with JQuery is using the .is(':focus') command or selecting the element with focus using $(':focus').  However, with Capybara this is not possible as Capybara Webkit or Selenium will ALWAYS tell you that all elements do not have focus as the browser itself does not have focus in the OS at the time of the test.

I have however found the solution to this problem, and developed a simple script to fix this issue when running your tests.  The problem lies with your browser's native match and query selectors being operating system aware, meaning that unless your browser and the web page tab has the focus within the operating system, then the :focus selector will not match ANY items within your document.  I've poked around inside JQuery to work out a way around this, and this can be done by simply forcing JQuery to use Sizzle and not optimise the selector queries using the browser's native functions.

If you include the following script https://gist.github.com/1166821 BEFORE you include JQuery, then your Selenium tests will pass the :focus tests.

For a complete write up of the issue, the solution and how to run tests, please review http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/9308775285/testing-focus-with-jquery-and-selenium-or

Hope that helps others who have this same issue.